# Superuser: mass system changes?

Tags: support

If you go to Superuser and scroll down a little, there are **many** entries with Splattne's name against them. I have gone in and can't see any sort of change, retag, answer or deleting.

Is this something the system does at random? However, why is it with a mods name instead of community or similar?

I looked in the tools as well, but I saw nothing under closed or deleted and as I haven't see this before, I couldn't help but wonder!

[image]

Comment: I'm a ROBOT. ;-)

Comment: +1 lol! I feel like an idiot... I did check a few, but I missed what it was you did! I should of checked more before writing this question!

Answer (score 6):

Click through to any one of the answers that he's updated/edited.

Most, if not all, of them have been rollbacks on posts by one particular user (now currently suspended) who changed their answer content to something along the lines of:

> [How do I delete a Super User account?](https://superuser.com/revisions/62971/list)

or

> [How do I delete a Super User account? I'm a ROBOT.](https://superuser.com/revisions/75098/list)

Comment: Thanks - I feel like a right idiot, I only clicked on 2/3 of them and must of completely missed it.

Comment: Yes, all rollbacks. Thanks for your answer, random!

Comment: Wonder if someone else has gained access to his account, seems odd to me that he would do that.

Comment: You would be surprised the things people do...